# How to use CSS3 linear-gradients?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Trying to figure out how the spacing between the lines can be reduced.

http://jsbin.com/tibipehu/1/edit

my code is based on linear gradient patterns by lea verou

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#zig-zag

Answer (score 1):

Change the gradient and background size elements

```
body {
background: 
linear-gradient(135deg, #ECEDDC 35%, transparent 25%) xpx 0px,
linear-gradient(225deg, #ECEDDC 35%, transparent 25%) xpx 0px,
linear-gradient(315deg, #ECEDDC 40%, transparent 25%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #ECEDDC 40%, transparent 25%);   
background-size: (x*2)px (x*2)px;
background-color: #EC173A;
}
```

In your example, you have used x = 50.

If you want to make the zigzags closer or further, you need to do some math - make the background size higher, then adjust the angles and percentages.

```
body {
background: 
linear-gradient(135deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
linear-gradient(225deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
linear-gradient(315deg, #abc 47%, transparent 30%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #abc 47%, transparent 25%);  
background-size: 40px 80px;
background-color: #123;
}
```

See playground with examples: http://jsbin.com/gudanovo/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
  <div class="box box4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box {width: 200px; float:left; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #333}

.box1 {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(225deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(315deg, #abc 48%, transparent 40%),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #abc 48%, transparent 40%);  
    background-size: 40px 80px;
    background-color: #123;
}

.box2 {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(225deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(315deg, #abc 40%, transparent 30%),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #abc 40%, transparent 25%);  
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-color: #123;
}

.box3 {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(225deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 20px 0px,
        linear-gradient(315deg, #abc 31%, transparent 30%),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #abc 31%, transparent 30%);  
    background-size: 40px 21px;
    background-color: #123;
}

.box4 {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 10px 0px,
        linear-gradient(225deg, #abc 35%, transparent 25%) 10px 0px,
        linear-gradient(315deg, #abc 40%, transparent 30%),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #abc 40%, transparent 25%);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-color: #123;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the lines smaller to. I want keep the lines the same size just the gap smaller.

Comment: Remember that multiple backgrounds only work on some browsers, and the standards way of stating gradients only works on the newest - make sure you have a fallback for older ones.

Answer (score 1):

I find this tool great help when making CSS3 gradients:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: This only allows you to create single gradients, not patterns created by overlaying multiple gradients.

Comment: Very true, my apologies.